# unique "key" prop. warning yet I have a key

Tags: json, reactjs

I am getting an error in my console,

my JSON is here https://dev.justinblayney.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/main-menu.json_.zip

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

What displays on my page is (So they are all unique, so WTF react)

KEY: 2429
KEY: 2430
KEY: 3859
KEY: 2421
KEY: 2802
KEY: 2428

On a side note, I'm discovering that using a function is a terrible way to get a JSON file, I also get memory leak warnings and every tutorial I see online uses classes or axios

Check the render method of `MyRoutes`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
MyRoutes@http://localhost:3000/react-wordpress-headless/static/js/main.chunk.js:63:81
div
Router@http://localhost:3000/react-wordpress-headless/static/js/0.chunk.js:35747:30
BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/react-wordpress-headless/static/js/0.chunk.js:35367:35
App@http://localhost:3000/react-wordpress-headless/static/js/main.chunk.js:94:1

```
    function MyRoutes() {
    
    const [myrt, setMyrt] = useState([]); 
  
    
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("main-menu.json" ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
    
        .then(json =>{
             setMyrt(json.items)}
              )
         });
        
    
    return (
        <>
            {Object.keys(myrt).map((ky, idx)=> (
            <>
             <h2>KEY: {myrt[ky].ID} </h2>
        <Route exact path={`/${myrt[ky].slug}`} component={Page} key={myrt[ky].ID}  /></>
            ))} 
        </>
  
    );
}
```

Comment: Your `key` isn't on the actual child, which is the fragment.

Comment: how do i fix that?

Comment: jonrsharpe is correct. Also the memory leak you are probably seeing is that you have passed no dependencies into useEffect so its running on every single render.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `key` prop should be defined on the first most element, in your case it is `React.Fragment`.

```js
function MyRoutes() {
  const [myrt, setMyrt] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('main-menu.json', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())

      .then((json) => {
        setMyrt(json.items);
      });
  });

  return (
    <>
      {Object.keys(myrt).map((ky, idx) => (
        <React.Fragment key={ky}>
          // ------------^
          <h2>KEY: {myrt[ky].ID} </h2>
          <Route exact path={`/${myrt[ky].slug}`} component={Page} key={myrt[ky].ID} />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: if the ordering can change at all do not use index as the key, react will get confused. Its better to use your ID

Comment: You are right, I've make the example only for pointing the staructure

Answer (score 1):

The `key` property is needed on the first-level of the list child element, thus I think in your example the React fragment within your `.map` needs to have this key.

Answer (score 1):

You need the key on the top component/tag that it's rendering on the map.
Example:
if you use a div

```
<div key={myrt[ky].ID} >
    <h2>KEY: {myrt[ky].ID} </h2>
    <Route exact path={`/${myrt[ky].slug}`} component={Page} />
</div>
```

Comment: so this then, as this is a dynamic route I dont want to wrap it in div {Object.keys(myrt).map((ky, idx)=> (
   
   <Route exact path={`/${myrt[ky].slug}`} component={Page} key={myrt[ky].ID}   />
   ))}

Answer (score 1):

For your memory leak you are calling the function get the JSON file infinite times because you have not specified any dependencies in the useEffect. So you set the data, it rerenders, then fetches again forever

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("main-menu.json" ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
    
        .then(json =>{
             setMyrt(json.items)}
              )
         }, [] /* Adding this only runs this once */);
```

Comment: thank you everyone for the help.. my app is not crashing my browser over time now

Comment: everyone is correct,  I don't know what answer to accept